# Merging linear chain of vertices in a Graph (in C++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have a large graph and it is represented in adjacency list. I would like to compress the graph by merging the linear chain of nodes. For example, if the edges are `a-c, b-c, c-d, d-e, e-f, e-g`:

```
a - c - d - e - f
    |       |
    b       g
```

Then `c-d, d-e` can be merged to a single node `x` and the new edge list should have `a-x, b-x, x-g`. I would like to implement it in C++, but I am wondering if there is any C++ graph library which handles this. Also, any suggestion for a efficient algorithm is appreciated.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105367/finding-bridges-in-a-graph-c-boost

Comment: I did't understand your example, so I took the liberty of adding ASCII art for the "problem" part.  You say the solution is `a-x, b-x, x-g` but this seems clearly wrong or inconsistent to me.  Can you draw the ASCII art for the solution  you want?  And can you explain why `c-d-e` can be merged but `a-c` cannot?

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck for the edit!! The ASCII art was not known to me. I hope you now understood why `a-c` cannot be merged. If not, here is a simple explanation. Just think `a` and `b` are two sources and some info coming from them and passes through `c-d-e` and then the info is divided into two parts and goes to `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you example might be broken so I am going to solve a slightly different one:

```
a - c - i - d - e - f
    |           |
    b           g
                |
                h
```

I think the solution looks like:

```
a - c - x - e - f
    |       |
    b       h
```

If you agree, then consider counting the number of times each vertex appears in the adjacency list, and storing the first two neighbors for each:

```
a b c d e f g h i
1 1 3 2 3 1 2 1 2
c c a i d e e g c
    b e g   h   d
```

The places where it is 2, we can consider collapsing: at `d`, `g`, and `i`:

```
d g i # candidates
2 2 2
i e c
e h d
```

Now you can see `g` has two neighbors not in the candidates, so simply delete `g` because it is a singleton "chain."  This leaves `d`, whose neighbor `i` is in the candidates, so collapse `d` and `i` into a new vertex `x` and you're done.

Comment: What differentiates the new `x` (which has order of 2) and `g`? You can delete `g` because one of its neighbors `h` has an order of `<= 2`. If you're going with replacing instead, you may want to collapse `g` and `h` instead of *simply deleting `g`*. Or you need to go further as Lior did and collapse all nodes of order `<= 2`.

Comment: Yes, I need to merge `g-h` also.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to remove all nodes with degree 2, merging their two neighbors into a single node.

Repeat the process till no such nodes are left.

The [Boost Graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) is usually a good way to store and work with graphs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762482/boost-graph-how-to-merge-two-vertices-contract-edge) how to merge vertices and contract the edge.

Comment: Actually I first implemented in C++ in this way for a big directed graph. My graph has almost 100K nodes, so I wanted to use some library which could make my life little easier. I will definitely take a look at Boost library. Thanks !!